# Upload a video to Vimeo using their API and curl (POST/PATCH)

Tags: curl, vimeo, vimeo-api

As I understand, one can use curl to make POST and PATCH requests;

POST: https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58

PATCH: [How to use PATCH verb with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306624/how-to-use-patch-verb-with-curl)

And the Vimeo API support POST and PATCH requests to upload a video;

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos

Here is my best guess so far as to how this can be written;

```
curl --request --url https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos \
--header 'Authorization: bearer {access_token}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' \
--data '{ "upload": { "approach": "tus", "size": "{size}" }}'
```

I suspect this is full of errors, and it also does not show how to upload a video with PATCH requests.

What would the correct curl command(s) look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For tus upload using the Vimeo API, it's a multi-step process:

1. Create the video object on Vimeo
2. Upload the video file data
3. Verify that Vimeo has received your video file

Step 1 is the POST request to `/me/videos`. If done correctly, you'll receive the full video response back, with an `"upload"` object containing an `"upload_link"`. Use the `upload_link` value for Step 2.

(Note that the `upload_link` should be on a Vimeo "tus" subdomain, like `files.tus.vimeo.com`. If you get an `upload_link` on a different Vimeo subdomain, then something went wrong with your request and the API is defaulting to another upload approach. You can also verify that you're getting a tus `upload_link` returned by checking the `approach` value nested in the `upload` object, it should return "tus".)

From your example, `--request` lacks the `POST` verb/action. Step 1 should look like this (also note that `-request`, `-header`, and `-data` are interchangeable with `-X`, `-H`, and `-d`, respectively):

```
curl -X POST https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' \
  -H 'Authorization: bearer XXXXXXXXX' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"upload":{"approach":"tus","size":"999999"}}'
```

Step 2, the actual file upload, is a PATCH to the `upload_link` returned from Step 1, with the request body containing the raw binary data of your video file:

```
curl --request PATCH upload_link \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/offset+octet-stream' \
  -H 'Tus-Resumable: 1.0.0' \
  -H 'Upload-Offset: 0' \
  --data-binary /path/to/file.ext
```

Step 3 is a HEAD request to that same `upload_link`, without the file data:

```
curl --request HEAD upload_link \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' \
  -H 'Tus-Resumable: 1.0.0' \
```

Depending on the `upload-length` and `upload-offset` headers returned, you may need to repeat step 2, resuming the upload from the last byte on Vimeo's servers.

Documentation for Vimeo's tus upload implementation is found here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#resumable-approach

Hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: few questions; 1) what does `bearer XXXXXXXXX` stand for, and how do I pass the auth key? Also, do subsequent calls require this authentication again? 2) Is there any way to just re-do the upload if it fails instead of byte-splitting it? 3) I was surprised to see that my `--data`/`-d` thoughts were about correct. It is really possible to just sent ASCII data like that? Thank you again, very much. I may have some more questions later.

Comment: @Roel 1) `XXXXXX` is where you should insert your auth token, and every request to `api.vimeo.com` requires a token: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#presenting-the-access-token. 2) In theory you could just perform a replacement/new version upload. Instead of doing a POST /me/videos, you'd do a POST to the `/versions` uri returned in Step 1. Replacement upload docs: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#replacing-a-source-file. 3) Yeah you should be able to use `-d` just as described, check curl docs for full details: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d

Comment: under step 2: how to give the data @TommyPenner can u give an example. I used the following code:-
`--data-binary '/home/abhi/intership/vimeo/1.mp4' `

Comment: Bringing this up from the dead, but I'm currently facing this problem and I'm unsure how to structure the body of step 2, particularly for uploading a file from a local device (computer or mobile phone), how the path would work.