# Vimeo and Tus: Upload stuck after few seconds without showing error on Android

Tags: android, vimeo, vimeo-android, tus

After a few seconds from the beginning of the video upload process, the progress bar stops without displaying any errors. I notice that the code freeze in attempt to execute `uploader.uploadChunk()` (after a few successful attempts). 
My previous question was [Vimeo upload : unexpected status code (404) while resuming upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61818110/vimeo-upload-unexpected-status-code-404-while-resuming-upload), so after changes I made I am sure that I have the correct `upload_link`

The code sample of my app is given below:

```
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Tus-Resumable", "1.0.0");
        headers.put("Authorization", getAuthHeader());
        headers.put("Accept", getAcceptHeader());
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/offset+octet-stream");
        headers.put("Upload-Length", "" + upload.getSize());
        headers.put("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        client.setHeaders(headers);

        TusUploader uploader = client.beginOrResumeUploadFromURL(upload, client.getUploadCreationURL());
        long totalBytes = upload.getSize();
        long uploadedBytes = uploader.getOffset();

        uploader.setChunkSize(1024);

        while (!isCancelled() && uploader.uploadChunk() > 0) {
            uploadedBytes = uploader.getOffset();
            publishProgress(uploadedBytes, totalBytes);
        }

        uploader.finish();
        return uploader.getUploadURL();
```

Also, here is the screenshot of my app:
[As you can see, upload progress is nearly 5 % completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okKaa.png)

Comment: Do you find solution to it??

Comment: @cyrus000 I found the solution. Just remove ` headers.put("Accept", getAcceptHeader());` from your code.

Comment: Getting ssl exception after few seconds.."javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0xb2aa5080: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe"

Comment: @cyrus000 seems like you are debuging your code. Try to run it without debug.