# Is there a way to make all your repositories / repos in GitHub Private from commandline or git?

Tags: git, github, repository, github-api

I'd like to loop through my GitHub account and set all my repo's as Private.

I searched a bit and am unsure how to do so?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To list all the public repositories of the user `abc` :

```
 curl --request GET https://api.github.com/users/abc/repos
```

To set a particular repository named `xyz` of the user `abc` as private :

```
curl -u abc:TOKEN --data "{\"private\": \"true\"}" --request PATCH https://api.github.com/repos/abc/xyz
```

To set all repositories owned by user `abc` as private :

```
curl --request GET https://api.github.com/users/abc/repos | jq --raw-output '.[] .name' |  xargs -I % curl -u abc:TOKEN --data "{\"private\": \"true\"}" --request PATCH https://api.github.com/repos/abc/%
```

**Note:**

- Replace `abc` with your username on GitHub
- Replace `TOKEN` with your personal access token for command line. To generate one follow [this](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)
- `curl` utility can be downloaded from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html)
- `jq` can be installed from [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
- If you are using Windows to run the command, use git-bash (for `xargs` utility compatibility)

**References:**

- [GitHub Developer API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/)
- [Authentication Methods](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/)
- [How to use PATCH verb with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16306624/10155936)
- [JSON processor online](https://jqplay.org/)
- [Using xargs with input from file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3593/using-xargs-with-input-from-a-file)

Comment: I'm getting an error: `curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL` when I try to run the third script.

Answer (score 0):

**POWERSHELL CODE**

For Windows users: it is Powershell code and it has no dependecies!

You need to run Powershell as Administrator!

You need to make TOKEN on GITHUB and paste in the Powershell code!

You can make TOKEN in GitHub/Settings/Developer settings/Personal access tokens/Generate new token.

You can get the ps file from GitHub repo:
[powershell_switch_repos_visibility_public_private](https://github.com/akicsike/powershell_switch_repos_visibility_public_private)

```
$Global:GITHUB_USER = ""
$Global:GITHUB_TOKEN = ""
$Global:REPOS_VISIBILITY_TYPE = "public" # which type of repos to convert: public or private
$Global:SET_TO_PRIVATE = "true" # if REPOS_VISIBILITY_TYPE = "public" then value must be "true", if REPOS_VISIBILITY_TYPE = "private" then value must be "false"

#start running
[GitHub]::reposToPrivate()


class GitHub {

    static [void] reposToPrivate(){

        $jsonStr = ""
        $pageNo = 1

        Do {
        
            $jsonStr = [GitHub]::getRepos($pageNo) # get json list of repos as json string
            $json = [GitHub]::convertJson($jsonStr) # convert json string
            [GitHub]::handleJsonForPrivate($json) # loop through repos list and switch private value

            $pageNo++
        
        } Until ($jsonStr -eq "[]") # if has no more page with repos than quits the loop
        

    }
    static [string] getRepos($pageNo){

        $endpoint = "https://api.github.com/user/repos?visibility=$($Global:REPOS_VISIBILITY_TYPE)&page=$($pageNo)"
        $resp = [GitHub]::callApi($endpoint, "GET", $false, @{})
        
        return $resp
    }
    static [void] handleJsonForPrivate($json){

        foreach($obj in $json){

            Write-Host "endpoint: $($obj.url)"
            $endpoint = $obj.url
            $resp = [GitHub]::setRepoToPrivate($endpoint)
            $respJson = [GitHub]::convertJson($resp)
            Write-Host "private = $($respJson.private)"
   
        }

    }
    static [string] setRepoToPrivate($endpoint){

        $postParams = @{"private"="$($Global:SET_TO_PRIVATE)"}
        $resp = [GitHub]::callApi($endpoint, "PATCH", $true, $postParams)

        return $resp
    }
    static [string] b64Authentication(){

        $AuthBytes  = [System.Text.Encoding]::Ascii.GetBytes("$($Global:GITHUB_USER):$Global:GITHUB_TOKEN")
        return [Convert]::ToBase64String($AuthBytes)

    }
    static [string] callApi([string]$endpoint, [string]$methodType, [bool]$hasPostParams, [hashtable]$postParams){

        $resp = ""

        if($hasPostParams){
            $resp = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{"Authorization"="Basic $([GitHub]::b64Authentication())"; "Accept"="application/vnd.github.v3+json"} -Method $methodType -Body ($postParams|ConvertTo-Json)
        } else {
            $resp = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $endpoint -Headers @{"Authorization"="Basic $([GitHub]::b64Authentication())"; "Accept"="application/vnd.github.v3+json"} -Method $methodType
        }

        return $resp
    }
    static [Object] convertJson($jsonStr){
    
        #Write-Host "jsonStr: $($jsonStr)"
        $json = $jsonStr | ConvertFrom-JSON

        return $json
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who feel more comfortable using js and node, Octokit is super helpful here:

1. [generate a github auth token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens#creating-a-fine-grained-personal-access-token) and paste it somewhere secure

   - for classic tokens, grant "repo" access
   - for fine-grained tokens, grant "Administration" -> "write" access
2. create an npm package (bash/zsh)

```bash
mkdir privatize
cd privatize
npm init -y
npm install octokit
```

3. paste the following into `index.mjs` (replace placeholders `YOUR_TOKEN_HERE` and `YOUR_USERNAME_OR_ORG_HERE` with your values)

```js
import { Octokit } from 'octokit';

const octokit = new Octokit({ auth: 'YOUR_TOKEN_HERE' });
const owner = 'YOUR_USERNAME_OR_ORG_HERE';

// fetch a list of repositories, even if they span across multiple pages
const repos = await octokit.paginate(octokit.rest.repos.listForUser, { username: owner });
// use this if you are updating repos for an org rather than a user
// const repos = await octokit.paginate(octokit.rest.repos.listForOrg, { org: owner });

const failed = [];
let i = 0;
for (const { name: repo } of repos) {
  console.log(`${++i}: ${repo}`);
  try {
    await octokit.request('PATCH /repos/{owner}/{repo}', {
      owner,
      repo,
      private: true,
    });
    console.log('success');
  }
  catch (e) {
    failed.push(repo);
    console.log('failed');
  }
}

console.log('failed updates:', JSON.stringify(failed, null, 2));
```

4. run it (bash/zsh)

```bash
node index.mjs
```